# How to change the properties of an AutoCAD object programmatically in Python

Tags: python, win32com, autocad, dxf, dwg

I want to automatically process a bunch of AutoCAD drawings using Python. To that end I need to change the properties of the drawing entities programmatically. I've been struggling for a while, to no avail.

This is the code I'm using to read the `.dxf` and open the `.dwg` files:

```py
import win32com.client
import dxfgrabber
import os

folder = r'C:\path\to\my\folder'
filename = 'my_file'

dwg_path = os.path.join(folder, filename + '.dwg')
dxf_path = os.path.join(folder, filename + '.dxf')

acad = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
doc = acad.Documents.Open(dwg_path)
acad.Visible = True

dxf = dxfgrabber.readfile(dxf_path)
```

Then I iterate over the objects placed in a layer called `FirstLayer` and select one of them:

```py
item = [obj for obj in dxf.entities if obj.layer == 'FirstLayer'][0]
```

This particular entity is a text object:

```py
In [1122]: type(item)
Out[1122]: dxfgrabber.dxfentities.Text

In [1123]: item.insert
Out[1123]: (4022.763956904745, 3518.371877135191, 0.0)

In [1124]: item.layer
Out[1124]: 'FirstLayer'

In [1125]: item.handle
Out[1125]: '298'
```

My goal is to change properties such as `color`, `layer`, etc. This is one of my attempts to move the text object to a different layer called `SecondLayer`:

```py
doc.SendCommand(f'CHPROP {item.insert[0]},{item.insert[1]} LA\n SecondLayer\n ')
```

I guess the problem is that the object cannot be selected through the coordinates of the insertion point. I also tried (unsuccessfully) to select the object by its handle using the following script:

```
_CHPROP (handent 298) _LA SecondLayer
```

Any ideas on how to work around this?

---

**EDIT**
I came up with the following solution before @Lee Mac posted his excellent answer:

```py
doc.SendCommand(f'CHPROP (handent "{item.handle}") \n_LA SecondLayer\n ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon issuing the `CHPROP` command, the subsequent object selection prompt will either require you to supply one or more entity names (which may be obtained by converting a handle using the AutoLISP `handent` function), or supplying a selection set (which may be obtained using the AutoLISP [`ssget`](http://lee-mac.com/ssget.html) function).

You were very close with your use of `handent`, however entity handles in AutoCAD are represented by hexadecimal strings and so you will need to supply the `handent` function with a string argument surrounded by double-quotes, e.g.:

```
(handent "298")
```

If the supplied handle is valid, `handent` will then return an entity name pointer:

```
_$ (handent "3B8")
<Entity name: 7ffff706880>
```

However, since `CHPROP` accepts a selection set argument, you needn't iterate over every entity, but instead simply supply `CHPROP` with a filter selection set, e.g.:

```
doc.SendCommand(f'CHPROP (ssget "_x" (list (cons 8 "FirstLayer"))) LA\n SecondLayer\n ')
```

Comment: I had to add a line feed after the list for the code to get to work. `doc.SendCommand(f'CHPROP (ssget "_x" (list (cons 8 "FirstLayer")))\n LA\n SecondLayer\n ')` made the trick. While waiting for an answer I came up with a solution (see my edited question). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The handle in DXF files is stored as HEX string, maybe AutoCAD requires an integer value, but I am not an AutoCAD expert (@LeeMac). Convert HEX string to int in Python by `int('298', 16)`.

Comment: Thank you Manfred :-)